dotnet restore fails in docker
I have created an ASP.NET Core Web API project, later I added docker support from Visual Studio. When I start the project with the container launch settings profile, it is working fine, but using the CMD docker build ., I get this error:

Error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

In the step of dotnet restore; I have tried multiple solutions posted on similar questions but nothing works for me.
I am using global protect VPN but I turned it off and still nothing changed

have you tried restarting docker after turning off vpn? could try running this command dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org before restore. just to be sure that there is no proxy setting interfering docker, could you check docker setting. run this command dotnet restore --verbosity detailed it might give some detail.

@JalpaPanchal for dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org I am getting
error: The name specified has already been added to the list of available package sources. Provide a unique name.

could try other suggestion as well and share the result of that

@JalpaPanchal the detailed dotnet restore the packages are loaded but it fails
All packages and projects are compatible with net8.0. Committing restore... Generating MSBuild file /src/obj/DockerTest.csproj.nuget.g.props. Generating MSBuild file /src/obj/DockerTest.csproj.nuget.g.targets. Writing assets file to disk. Path: /src/obj/project.assets.json Writing cache file to disk. Path: /src/obj/project.nuget.cache Persisting dg to /src/obj/DockerTest.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json Failed to restore /src/DockerTest.csproj

could you please check if the docker container can access internet or not. are you using any proxy?
